# Problem With Power Supply of ATMEGA328P and USART Peripheral

Tags: microcontroller, avr, uart, embedded, atmel

I am learning Atmega328p USART peripheral. I wrote a simple code to send and receive data from a computer through a FTDI chip. In my code I actually use two led for indication of working. 1st LED which is connected PINB0 will toggle after a BYTE transmission . The 2nd LED will toggle if a successful reception of 1 BYTE from computer.  Now I burned the code.And things were happening as they should happen. The 1st LED is toggling indicating data transmission . And the 2nd LED is not TOGGLING as I did not connect FTDI chip till now. Then I unplugged my usbasp and powered microcontroller with a cellphoine charger of constant 5v which i measured with my oscilloscope(with a 1uf capacitor in supply rail). Now interesting thing happen. The 2nd LED is blinking randomly indicating that microcontroller is receving BYTE through its RX pin. But I haven`t connected the FTDI driver till now and the RX pin is without any connection. What is happening here?

Here is my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000ul
volatile unsigned char ReceivedByte;

int main(void)
{
DDRB |=(1<<PINB0)|(1<<PINB1);
int reg_value=12;
UBRR0L= (unsigned char) reg_value;
UBRR0H= (unsigned char) (reg_value>>8);
UCSR0B |=(1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXCIE0);
UCSR0C |=(1<<USBS0)|(1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<UCSZ01); //2 stopbit,8data bit
sei();
    while (1) 
    {
        while(!(UCSR0A &(1<<UDRE0)) ) //polling
        UDR0='a';
         PORTB ^=(1<<PINB0);
        _delay_ms(500);

    }
}
ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    ReceivedByte=UDR0;
    PORTB ^=(1<<PINB1);
}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I can not add code as text.It looks horrible when I am trying to paste the code in the editor

Comment: You then select it and press Ctrl-K

Comment: @Eugene Sh .That worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1):

> the RX pin is without any connection.

A floating pin can easily pickup noise from all kind of sources. I would only be worried if you receive data whilst the pin is pulled high or low.

Just to add: that it seems idle in one condition and receiving on another may just be a matter of noise level or DC level at which the noise comes in.

Comment: Oldfart Thank you! I am wondering what is the noise source!! Btw when the pin is pulled high or low problem solves.

Comment: Oldfart I am also having another problem. I have checked there is no pblm with FTDI cause I have chacked by connecting it`s TX and RX pin together and it can echo back sent data from my terminal software. Now I have connected the FTDI chip with PC and Microcontroller.When I send data from my computer to microcontroller it works fine. But I am also sending letter 'a' from my microcontroller.It should be showed in my terminal software.But it shows nothing.

Comment: For a different problem it is best you start a new thread. (Also check you voltage and baudrate.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem. It is silly I haven`t put a comma after polling.Now I am wondering why that happened.